# How to convert string into integers python

Tags: python, string, integer

I am fairly new to the python language, but had stumbled across something I found troubling. Is there a way to turn a string into an integer?

No, I do not mean how to convert a string that is a number like this:

```
int('1')
```

I am positive I can do something like this:

```
foo = 'foo'
foo = 10
int(foo)
```

But is there an easier way to do this, rather than having to type it like that?

In the context that I a trying to put it in, I am trying to turn the value of a card, such as a Jack, equivalent to 10 in a card game.

Comment: You want a function to convert `"foo"` to `10`?

Comment: `foo = 'foo'` followed by `foo = 10` is pointless as that assigns `foo` to 10.

Comment: You want to convert a string to an int that is easier than `int('1')`? What kind of shorthand are you looking for because `int('1')` I think is very short already.

Comment: @Mushy0364 What would the result be for `"bar"`?

Comment: @Mushy0364 Why do you want to do this? What is the program that this is a part of? Your question doesn't really make sense as-is

Comment: Please do clarify the question. I detect [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @qxz Say I am trying to make cards such as a Jack equivalent to the value of 10.

Comment: @Mushy0364: You may want to create a dict mapping cards to their values.

Comment: @Mushy0364 What format is the card name in, specifically? Give us sample inputs/outputs. Something like `"jack" -> 10`?

Comment: @qxz It's found in a list of cards, where the computer randomly selects a card, with values such as ['Ace','Jack','Queen',etc.]

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for the suggestion, I may look into that.

Comment: @Mushy0364 Please edit your question to include as much detail specific to your problem as possible.

Comment: You're not converting strings to integers, in this case. You're looking up a mapping of string values to integer values. A dictionary is the canonical implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to turn the value of a card, such as a Jack, equivalent to 10 in a card game

You need to check the string - if digit, then convert, else get the corresponding value.

```
def get_card_value(s):
  if s.isdigit() and (1 < int(s) < 10):
    return int(s)
  elif s.lower() == 'jack':
    return 10
  elif s.lower() == 'queen':
    return 11
  elif s.lower() == 'king':
    return 12
  else:
    return -1  # Unknown
```

Modify accordingly for different values and aces

Answer (score 1):

Since [your goal is to map specific cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029033/how-to-convert-string-into-integers-python/41029144#comment69265665_41029033) (as in a game of blackjack) to their values, make a `dict` for lookup up front:

```
# 2-10
name_to_value = {str(num): num for num in range(2, 11)}
# Face cards
name_to_value.update(dict.fromkeys(('Jack', 'Queen', 'King'), 10))
# Ace is special
name_to_value['Ace'] = 11  # If it's blackjack, you might want to special case Ace
```

Then use it to convert later, e.g.:

```
>>> name_to_value['Jack']
10
>>> name_to_value['9']
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment I think you may be looking to assign an integer value to a string key.  For that, you can use a dictionary.  Declare:

```
>>> cards = {"jack": 10, "queen": 10}
>>> print(cards["jack"])
10
```

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately that's the only way that you can declare a variable type in Python 3. What you are doing is casting the string to an integer. The way that you are doing it is the best way.

Comment: There is no "casting" of any kind involved here. A `str` object containing `"foo"` is bound to the name `foo`, then `foo` is rebound to an `int` object containing `10`. Nothing is changing type, `foo` is just being pointed at a completely different object.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable yet.